# "expand"/join SQL select by JSON values on MSSQL

Tags: json, t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2017

I'm presented with a problem where I have a table which has two columns which contain JSON data. I've been reading through Microsoft's documentation on working with JSON in MSSQL but can't seem to wrap my head around my specific problem.

Consider this rather simple example of a single row from my table:
[image]

What I'm looking to achieve is join the values from `LocationsJSON` and `AssigneesJSON` onto itself and hopefully end up with something along these lines:
[image]

It seems to be possible when looking at Microsoft's documentation but I can't seem to approach the problem the right way.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? Relevant because JSON support was added into v.2016. Please adjust question tags to reflect this.

Comment: I'm using 2017 on Azure - thank you for the hint, I'll update the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON support was added in SQL Server 2016. You won't be able to parse JSON strings in earlier versions.

You can use `CROSS APPLY` in the FROM clause with any function that returns a table to perform a cross "join" with the function's results. The function you need in this case is [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server).

The following code :

```
declare @table table (id int, json1 nvarchar(max), json2 nvarchar(max))

insert into @table values (1,'["a","b"]','["1","2"]')

select id,vals1.value as V1,vals2.value as V2
from @table t 
    cross apply openjson(t.json1) vals1
    cross apply openjson(t.json2) vals2
```

Will return :

```
id  V1  V2
1   a   1
1   a   2
1   b   1
1   b   2
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice and elegant. And much easier to approach than what I had made it up to be :)

Answer (score 2):

**AND,** other way come to in mind which is older style `XML`.nodes method with apply `CROSS JOIN`

```
with cte as
(
    select 
       Id, Name, LocationJSON,
       cast(ltrim(replace(replace(replace(j.value('.', 'varchar(600)'), '{', ''), '}', ''), '"', ''))  as int)  Locations
    from
    (
       select Id, Name, LocationJSON,
         cast('<X>'+replace(LocationJSON, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' as xml) NLocationJSON 
       from table
    )a cross apply NLocationJSON.nodes ('/X') as Location(J)
), cte1 as
(
    select 
       Id, Name, AssigneesJSON,
       ltrim(replace(replace(replace(A.value('.', 'varchar(600)'), '{', ''), '}', ''), '"', ''))   Assignees
    from
    (
       select Id, Name, AssigneesJSON,
         cast('<X>'+replace(AssigneesJSON, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' as xml) NAssigneesJSON
       from table
    )a cross apply NAssigneesJSON.nodes ('/X') as Assignees(A)
)

select c.Id, c.Name, 
       c.LocationJSON, c1.AssigneesJSON, 
       c.Locations, c1.Assignees 
from cte c , cte1 c1 -- CROSS JOIN
```

**Result :**

```
Id  Name    LocationJSON    AssigneesJSON   Locations   Assignees
100 Foo     {"123", "456"}  {"abc", "def"}  123         abc
100 Foo     {"123", "456"}  {"abc", "def"}  123         def
100 Foo     {"123", "456"}  {"abc", "def"}  456         abc
100 Foo     {"123", "456"}  {"abc", "def"}  456         def
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution for your scenario will be

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE  (Id  INT , [Name] VARCHAR(100),LocationsJSON VARCHAR(100) ,AssigneesJSON VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO @MyTable
    SELECT * FROM 
    ( VALUES 
         (100,'Foo','["123","456"]','["abc","def"]' )

    )T (Id  , [Name] ,LocationsJSON  ,AssigneesJSON   )

    SELECT MT.Id, MT.Name,  MT.LocationsJSON ,MT.AssigneesJSON, R1.[value]  as Locations , R2.[value] as Assignees FROM @MyTable MT
    CROSS APPLY
    (
     SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(MT.LocationsJSON)
    )R1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
     SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(MT.AssigneesJSON)
    )R2
```

Output:

```
Id  Name    LocationsJSON   AssigneesJSON   Locations   Assignees
-----------------------------------------------------------------
100 Foo     ["123","456"]   ["abc","def"]   123         abc
100 Foo     ["123","456"]   ["abc","def"]   123         def
100 Foo     ["123","456"]   ["abc","def"]   456         abc
100 Foo     ["123","456"]   ["abc","def"]   456         def
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Much appreciated.